# Applying for UK visa with multiple bank accounts

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for an UK visa, and while I am sure that I have more than enough money to travel, I am a bit confused which bank statements should I present.

I've read a great answer at [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) , but it deals mostly with *one* bank account, and I have many of them.

I'm employed at one of the biggest Russian IT companies, earning ~£2000 per month in ordinary salary and somewhat more (~£3000 per month on average) in company options (stocks). The former can be easily proved by a letter from my employer, my bank statement and tax statements. The latter is a bit more difficult, as these options vest irregularly, and I sell them irregularly.

I have many bank accounts:

- One account (in RUR) where I have my salary deposited. I seldom spend money from this account, most often I transfer them to the second account (see below).
- One account (in RUR) in another bank; from time to time I transfer the money from the first account to this account and do most of the spendings from here.
- Also I had an account (in RUR) in a third bank that I used to have my salary deposited to, but I closed it in January, switching to the abovementioned account.

The balance on these accounts vary between £500 and £5000.

- Also I have two accounts in USD and EUR in the second bank, the total balance is about £10000, but they see little activity (only when I sell some options and do investments, see below). These are the money that I actually am going to spend in the UK (although I expect total spending for the trip to be about £5000-7000).

The bulk of money I spend for investments, and I have three investments accounts totalling at about £80000. Like with any long-term investments, there is little activity, but these accounts may explain where my earnings go to and why I do not accumulate large sums on my main bank accounts.

So,

- Should I present bank statements from *all* (five) my bank accounts? Will not this overburden whoever will be inspecting my application?
- Should I also present statements from investments accounts?
- Should I present some proofs that I have options as they form more than a half of my income?
- Should I probably add some explanation of all my bank usage patterns (similar to what I have written here)?

---

Also (should I ask this as a separate question?), I am going to UK with my wife, who does not earn that much. Should I write a sponsor letter and attach all my statements to her application also, or they will be processing our applications together in any case?

The answer linked above says:

> In these cases the primary applicant's bank statements will be used to assess the family's circumstances as a whole. The UK approves thousands of family applications each year.

So it implies that there is a "primary applicant", so that family applications are processed together. Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include statements of all banks and other places you have money.
The statements are to show you have enough money and an regular income that allows you to spend the expected amount while in the UK.

For your wife you should be able to apply together or at least use your application to show her financial position.